following services are not running: web. - node.js
i am using aws elastic beanstalk node.js
but following services are not running: web. occured
github action runs but 'following services are not running: web' appears
and when i link to elastic beanstalk domain, only congratulations page appear even though i use "~~/signup" or "~~/reviews"
webpack.config.js
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  context: __dirname + "/src",
  entry: {
    app: "../index.js",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "main.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  target: "node",
  externalsPresets: {
    node: true,
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
};

package.json
{
  "name": "cicd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node index.js",
    "start:dist": "webpack --mode production & node ./dist/main.js",
    "start": "node main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.2.0",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.3.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.17",
    "@babel/node": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.15",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "swagger-autogen": "^2.23.7",
    "swagger-cli": "^4.0.4",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.8",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}

procfile
web: npm install & npm run start

